# Traducir una columna de esp a inglés de un DataFrame en python, dato a dato

Tags: python

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

translator = google_translator()  
translated = translator.translate(df['info'], lang_src='es', lang_tgt='en')  
print(translated)
```

Pero me da este error: 404 (Not Found) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown

Creo que es porque estoy metiendo la columna entera, como podría leer dato a dato la columna con un for, e ir traduciendo todo, son muchos datos y se que llevará tiempo

al final hice un for de esta manera:

```
import time
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator() 
principio=0

t=0.7

for j in range(len(df)-principio):
    print(j+principio)
    time.sleep(t)
    df['info'][j+principio] = 
    translator.translate(df['info'][j+principio], dest='en').text
```

pero tengo el siguiente problema: como la base de datos es muy grande, meti el sleep() por que sino el programa petaba y al tiempo me saltaba error, y con el sleep() si que aguanta más, traduciendo dato a dato, pero llega un momento que salta el error de: Time Out, sabéis como solucionar eso?

Comment: Me parece que ese modulo ya no funciona bien. Pero podrias probar usando apply, que aplica una funcion a una serie y es mas rapido que un bucle for.

Comment: Me pasa lo siguiente ahora, te lo escribo arriba, graciias

Comment: A mi no me funciona el módulo, me manda un error completamente diferente. Es posible que ese modulo haya dejado de funcionar bien... Te recomiendo mirar la pregunta que te pasé.

Comment: Sii, ya veo pero lo que pasa, es que en la pregunta que me has mandado, lo que traduce son las frases que el mismo introduce, no la propia columna de un csv, o si se puede, no sabría como hacerlo. Gracias Dante por responder

Comment: A veces, en Stack Overflow, se "reutilizan" las respuestas para no tener preguntas que se podrían responder de manera casi igual. Por lo que a veces, no tendrás una solución personalizada recién salida del horno.

Comment: En el caso de la pregunta que te mandé, es casi la misma historia (de hecho, el lo saca de excel en vez de un csv). Lo que importa, es que tanto aqui, como en esa pregunta y mi respuesta, primero armas la columna a traducir con los textos en el idioma de origen y luego *aplicas* la función translator.translate sobre cada valor de la columna.

Comment: Genial, Muchas gracias Dante

Comment: De nada Señor23 c: